# Does Tsan instrument inline assembly?

Tags: c++, c, data-race, thread-sanitizer

I have some code in my project in inline assembly, does TSAN instrument it?
let's look at this example:

T0: x++

T1: (inline assembly code) MOV x, 2;

will we get data race here(assuming no sync at all)? if so, does it instrument all assembly memory access such as XADD, etc?

Comment: That does not seem to be [documented](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html), but my guess would be that ThreadSanitizer does not see into inline assembly.  It ought to be fairly easy to test, however.  Have you tried?

Comment: thanks, looks like it doesn't. so an inline assembly code is not checked